# Go, %v format invoking String() for a nested struct

Tags: go

In the following code, I would expect `fmt.Printf("%v\n", a)` to invoke String() of its member of type myTypeB, but this is not happening ? Why ?

```
package main

import "fmt"
type myTypeA struct {
     b myTypeB
}
type myTypeB struct {
    c string
    d int

}

func (b myTypeB) String() string {
    return "myTypeB custom"
}

func main() {

   a:= myTypeA{myTypeB{"hello", 1}};
   b:= myTypeB{"hello", 1}
   fmt.Printf("%v\n", a)
   fmt.Printf("%v\n", b)
}
```

[Playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/lIuRfBRKkM)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fmt` doesn't look for `fmt.Stringer` recursively.

If the argument is a `fmt.Stringer`, it will invoke the `String()` method, and print the results. If it doesn't have a `String()` method, `fmt` will iterate over the fields using reflection to obtain the value.